# What effect does Kairoseki's have on Haki?

Tags: one-piece

When a Devil Fruit user is locked with Kairoseki, is there any affect on his Haki abilities.
Like in episode 627, couldn't luffy use Conqueror's Haki when he was in the cage made of Kairoseki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kairoseki has no effect on haki. Rayleigh could use Haki while being chained in the auction house ( during the sabaody archipelago arc).Also haki is inborn quality in every living thing in one piece world as said by Rayleigh. And kairoseki only affects devil fruit users. Non devil fruit users are not affected by kairoseki. So they can use haki however they like still being chained.

Comment: But was rayleigh shackled with kairoseki, as far as I know rayleigh doesn't have a devil fruit power so he probably went for a frail old man and doesn't had kairoseki shackles.

Comment: @Wouter as far as I remember I think the giant with him did say something regarding the chain. Also, later Rayleigh explained that all living thing had haki ability so kairoseki might not affect. Kairoseki is mentioned as hardest substance and property to subdue devil fruit powers. Its effect on haki isn't mentioned.

Comment: am i correct in assuming that rayleigh didn't have devil fruit powers?

Comment: Yes. Rayleigh doesn't have any devil fruit power. He swam through calm belt to reach amazon lily. If he had any devil fruit power then he couldn't have swam through the grand line.

Comment: Kairouseki does seems to prevent Haki to be used. Rayleigh was only able to use it because he was the vice Pirate King and has a training level beyond the conceivable in the manga storyline so far, a level Luffy is currently struggling to achieve. But everytime any other haki-enabled user was arrested with Kairouseki, their Haki skills wore off. Happened specially with Luffy, as we can see in chapter 936 where he uses Haoshoku Haki instantly after being freed of the Kairouseki handcuffs. There is in fact no canon saying anything about this, but the storyline evidence is verifiable by exclusion

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't really explained. We still don't know about the full extent of Haki or Kairōseki. Plus episode 627 is a filler so I wouldn't take what happens in there seriously, it is not canon. The anime is notorious for contradicting itself. Oda might explain Haki and Kairōseki more in the manga later on.

Answer (score 0):

As i see it, the Kairoseki (sea stone was a translation i once memorized) makes the devil-fruit user physically weak, unable to move. And as you know, Luffy's ability is pretty much physical in any aspect, meaning when he feels weakened in his body, he also starts to feel helpless in his mind (until emotions tend to make him go berserk). Apparently that's just enough to make him lose his inner cool and not be able to use haki as he wished to.

Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

[According to Smoker](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_169), [Kairoseki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Seastone#Effects_on_Devil_Fruit_Users) works to incapacitate devil fruit eaters because it gives off the same wavelength as the sea. In addition, [Shanks used Haoshoku no Haki](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3iSqsrEsDI) on the sea monster that took his arm while swimming. That means Haki is unaffected by the sea's wavelength and therefore unaffected by Kairoseki.

There are many situations where Luffy could use Haoshoku no Haki and chooses not to, especially on Whole Cake Island. So I think it is fair to assume he cannot use it in every situation. Because we cannot yet know exactly what situations he can use it in, we should look at the situations in which he does and compare. [Everytime Luffy uses his Haoshoku no Haki](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4o8ARK0AgcU), he is in one of two states: either in a totally desperate situation or in perfect health while calm and collected. In episode 627, however, he is not in a totally desperate situation (although Chopper is being beaten, he is not in danger of dying) and Luffy is not perfectly calm and collected.

It may be fair, then, to assume Luffy could not use his Haoshoku no Haki in this particular instance.